# Creating barcodes using JSBarCode

Tags: node.js, express, html5-canvas, barcode

I am using [JSBarCode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsbarcode) to try and generate barcodes for assets. I need to be able to create a static barcode then I think I can get the dynamic part myself. My code so far is direct copy from the docs found on the link above. I would think the docs would give a working example to base my code off. Maybe I did the code wrong, I have the code below and I have done the NPM installs already for jsbarcode and canvas.

Server side code:

```
var JsBarcode = require('jsbarcode');
var Canvas = require("canvas");

var canvas = new Canvas();
JsBarcode(canvas, "Hello");
JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
```

HTML:

```
<svg class="barcode"
  jsbarcode-format="upc"
  jsbarcode-value="123456789012"
  jsbarcode-textmargin="0"
  jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
```

I am getting an error when I try and run my node app. It is long and not really much use to me but hopefully one of you can understand it. Here it is:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/jsbarcode/bin/help/getRenderProperties.js:84
        var selector = document.querySelectorAll(string);
                                ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at querySelectedRenderProperties (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/jsbarcode/bin/help/getRenderProperties.js:84:26)
    at getRenderProperties (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/jsbarcode/bin/help/getRenderProperties.js:37:10)
    at JsBarcode (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/jsbarcode/bin/JsBarcode.js:63:60)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/server/index.js:31:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/server.js:4:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

If you have suggestions on a better package that can read and generate custom barcodes please let me know so I can look into it.

Comment: I tried commenting out each line to see what was the issue, `JsBarcode(".barcode").init();` seems to cause the error above. But I can't get it to work without that. I have since also tried `$('.barcode').JsBarcode("546786756445465", {
  width: 1,
  height: 40
});` with no luck. Removed the settings on the `svg` to test as well with no luck

Comment: You might want to try another symbology, if this is not for point-of-sale scanning systems. UPC / EAN are not the most efficient and they come with restrictions (numbers only, limited # of characters). I'd recommend Code 128 if you are just going to be slapping labels on assets.

Comment: @BrianAnderson  Code 128 is the plan, I planned to change the data stuff for the barcodes once I got them working. That is priority one right now.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the JSBarcode library. It seems pretty comprehensive. I have a little over a hundred lines of Javascript I've been using to do my barcodes for the last 4 years. You're welcome to take a look at: https://codepen.io/notionovus/pen/GMwZBx.

Comment: @BrianAnderson Is this your custom code or did you find it somewhere online with docs to use? I like it and it seems simple enough I could use it without issues. Does it create random barcodes or does it create the same one just with different text, height and width depending on the requirements set? Just thinking of how I can implement this weather I need a random generator or not, more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcjEDAghkmFUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAck4DAxY8F10AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAvnk9E4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATU4CA7CME0sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAck4DAxY8F10AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAvnk9E4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATUoCA+Jw8kAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASTUCAqHeHtMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="5" height="70">
```

I built a little barcode generator that does Code128 back in 2014. I'm blowing the dust off the code and putting it into circulation on [codepen](https://codepen.io/notionovus/pen/GMwZBx?editors=1010). It's 100% client side, plain vanilla Javascript. No jQuery, no libraries, no fonts, no server necessary. You can run it disconnected from a thumb drive. All the barcodes are generated by the browser.

The [old code](http://brian-p-anderson.github.io/JS-Barcodes/) should work in any browser that supports javascript, and it generates HTML "img" tags, so the result is something you can embed in a "div" and display on a page even if the client has JS turned off. It's all MIT license, so you are free to download and use with or without the U/I.

I'm working on an app that prints out sheets of barcodes, so stay tuned if you are doing barcode publishing en masse.

Comment: How would one store this in a database and make it readable later on?

Comment: The snipet above spells out the value "123456789012" in a Code 128 barcode which requires around 7,000 bytes of text with no special or control characters. A simple key-value store could be used to place the "img" tags as a text block in the value and use the value stored in the barcode as the key. Feed the javascript code the keys to create the text that displays in the large text area in the codepen and instead of displaying the images, save the large string in the value store indexed by the key. When displaying retrieve the strings from storage and place them inside "div" tags.

Comment: How did you create the images for the individual digits? Can JsBarcode do that?

Comment: @Melab, My original code (circa 2012) created an image for each character, but I found it more efficient to build a generic bar rendering engine that renders bars based on height, width and a binary code from "00000" to "11111" for each segment (5 bits / segment). Another section of code creates the "1"s and "0"s based on rules of the symbology (Code 128, Code 39, UPC, etc.). The result is ~100 lines of JS that can be embedded in any page where I want to print a barcode. The images were created with MS Paint, converted to base64 and embedded in the JS source code in the codepen link above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jsBarcode library](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode) to do that see a demo below

```js
JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbarcode/3.8.0/JsBarcode.all.js"></script>
<svg class="barcode" jsbarcode-format="upc" jsbarcode-value="012345678912" jsbarcode-textmargin="0" jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
        </svg>
```